# Residue of $\frac{z^3}{(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)}$ at $z=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Residue of $\dfrac{z^3}{(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)}$ at $z=\infty$.

Well, the total sum of residues is zero. But the given answer says 6.

We calculate residues with $Res\;f(a)=\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\left[\dfrac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}[(z-a)^nf(z)]\right]_{z=a}$, but that can't be used here ..

I don't know how to proceed. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: The sum of _all_ residues is $0$, that includes the residues at $z=1,2,3$.

Comment: we calculate residues by $Res\;f(a)=\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\left[\dfrac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}[(z-a)^nf(z)]\right]_{z=a}$ That can't be used here ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\operatorname{Res} \left[ {f\left( z \right),z = 1} \right] = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to 1} \left( {z - 1} \right)f\left( z \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to 1} \frac{{{z^3}}}
{{\left( {z - 2} \right)\left( {z - 3} \right)}} = \frac{1}
{2},$$
$$\operatorname{Res} \left[ {f\left( z \right),z = 2} \right] = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to 2} \left( {z - 2} \right)f\left( z \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to 2} \frac{{{z^3}}}
{{\left( {z - 1} \right)\left( {z - 3} \right)}} =  - 8,$$
$$\operatorname{Res} \left[ {f\left( z \right),z = 3} \right] = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to 3} \left( {z - 3} \right)f\left( z \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to 3} \frac{{{z^3}}}
{{\left( {z - 1} \right)\left( {z - 2} \right)}} = \frac{{27}}
{2}$$
We have
$$\operatorname{Res} \left[ {f\left( z \right),z = 1} \right] + \operatorname{Res} \left[ {f\left( z \right),z = 2} \right] + \operatorname{Res} \left[ {f\left( z \right),z = 3} \right] + \operatorname{Res} \left[ {f\left( z \right),z = \infty } \right] = 0.$$
So
$$\operatorname{Res} \left[ {f\left( z \right),z = \infty } \right] =  - \left( {\operatorname{Res} \left[ {f\left( z \right),z = 1} \right] + \operatorname{Res} \left[ {f\left( z \right),z = 2} \right] + \operatorname{Res} \left[ {f\left( z \right),z = 3} \right]} \right) = -6$$

Comment: Thank you for the help .. learning something new can be painful at times ..